# How to ignore set of rows while doing pandas filtering?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this data set and i want to print all rows and columns except [1,3]

```
    w              x            y            z
a   -1.749765   0.342680    1.153036    -0.252436
b   0.981321    0.514219    0.221180    -1.070043
c   -0.189496   0.255001    -0.458027   0.435163
d   -0.583595   0.816847    0.672721    -0.104411
e   -0.531280   1.029733    -0.438136   -1.118318
```

I have this data set and i want to print all rows and columns except [1,3]

```
df.iloc[~[1,2,3],:]
```

Somewhat like this but getting error  can anyone help

Comment: do you mean `df.iloc[:3]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [select pandas rows by excluding index number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256761/select-pandas-rows-by-excluding-index-number). In your case `bad_df = df.index.isin(['b', 'c', 'd'])`. Remember that dataframes are 0 indexed, so 0 = a, 1 = b.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `drop`

```
df.drop([1,2,3])
```