# How to get a subset of rows in a dataframe excluding a few rows python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> I want to get the a subset of a dataframe given the row indexes i don't want... How >can i do it?

> I know i can give

```
df.iloc[[1,2,6,8,3]]
```

> And get these rows but how do i get the dataframe excluding these rows?

> The indexs can be anything

Comment: This is already answered here: [select pandas rows by excluding index number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256761/select-pandas-rows-by-excluding-index-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `drop` method :

```
df = df.drop([1, 2, 3])
```

if your index has names you should specify `axis=0` as python will interpret strings as column names and will define axis as 1 by default.

Comment: I don't want to drop them... But i guess i can get a temporary dataframe if i dont specify inplace argument... Thanks man it works

Comment: @JackFroster drop will not drop the columns if you dont specify parameter ```inplace=true```. Just remove the assignment operator and use it as normal. If it works could you accept the answer. its a tick on the left of the answer.